# How to create a Windows Vista shortcut to a specific Hotmail message?

Tags: outlook.com, links, windows

When I open a message in Hotmail and create a Windows Vista shortcut to that specific Hotmail message then click the created shortcut I see a list of messages in the folder, not the specific message I was viewing.

Is there a way to create a shortcut that directly opens the desired message?

Comment: Are you viewing your Hotmail account online in your web browser or in an application such as Windows Mail or Outlook?

Comment: @music2myear, good point. I use Hotmail on the web.

Comment: I've done some googling and haven't found any way to do this yet. If it would work, I think it would be by some link created inside the application rather than by simply copy/pasting the address bar text.

Comment: @music2myear, thanks for your followup, I thought it would be easy, specially when one is already logged on.

Comment: Most web applications (web sites that look and act like programs more than traditional sites) do not have friendly page-specific links.